# How can i position a div always above another div? (not overlaying!)

Tags: html, css

How can i position the `div#sky` always exact above the `div#house`, while the `img#roof` is always on the bottom of `div#sky`?

`div#plot` must be always on the bottom of the browser as well.

The House should awalys has an aspect ratio of 1:1.09 and positioned at the bottom of the browser.

Above that house, the roof should be placed.

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="sky">
        <img id="roof" src="img/roof.png" alt="roof">
    </div>
    <div id="plot">
        <div id="house">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
div#main {
  border-bottom: 1px solid dimgray;
  height: 90%;
  margin: 5vh auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
div#sky {
  background: white;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
div#plot {
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
div#house {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 2.4vw solid black;
  border-right: 2.4vw solid black;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 25.844%;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.2%;
}
img#roof {
  bottom: 0.2vw;
  height: auto;
  left: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
}
```

Example:
http://www.kunkel-dienstleistungen.com/dev/

Comment: Please avoid using `!important` it's a very bad practice :)

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what you mean, but have you tried adding `top: 0;` and removing the `bottom` style on `img#roof`?

Comment: @Py.: Removed - old habits. ;)

Comment: @JosephMarikle I re-edited the description above, maybe it's more understandable?

Comment: is something like [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/qck4zk1p/) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> position the `div#sky` always exact above the `div#house`

Natural flow dictates that that is already the case

> while the `img#roof` is always on the bottom of `div#sky`

Take of `bottom: 0.2vw;` and replace it with `top: 100%;`.  Then add `position:relative;` to `div#sky`.  The `top` value is pretty self explanatory.  It will place the top of your `#roof` element 100% of its offset parent's height from its offset parent's top edge.  Adding relative positioning to `#sky` makes it the offset parent of `#roof`.

> `div#plot` must be always on the bottom of the browser as well.

You've got that part down (hehe... no pun intended).

> The House should awalys has an aspect ratio of 1:1.09 and positioned at the bottom of the browser.

This part may be an issue, but it's too hard to tell with the lack of a solid demo.  You have a demo in place, but it has a few issues.  It doesn't have anything in the `#sky` element, so I don't know if the "sky" will be an image element, background image, or simple color.

Comment: I placed my code into https://jsfiddle.net/uk5jorxc/ with your suits. The problem is, the house should always keep his aspect-ratio, while the roof is on top of that house. Beside this, the house should placed on the bottom of the browser.

Comment: @ambiente1 That'll be very difficult with how you have it set up now.  Any reason why the "roof" isn't a part of the "house" like so: https://jsfiddle.net/0mu2xvgp/?

Comment: That's it! I don't really know why don't do it this way, oh my goodness... ;) Any hint, why each of the 2 floors not having 50% of the house-height? It's because the height 0 and is sized by padding or? Any workaround?

Comment: @ambiente1 The floor issue is also complicated due to the format, but you can either give them `position:absolute;` and give the second one `top:50%;` or you can give them both a wrapper with `padding-top:50%;`, make them `position:relative`, and give the wrapper `position:absolute` with `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` set to 0.  The second approach is a little complicated, so here's another demo: https://jsfiddle.net/v14y5bo7/

Comment: Thanks Joseph, you made my day! :) I prefer to use the 1st method and it fits my mind. Very very much thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is using flexbox styles to adapt the sky height dynamically. Just nearly like a 'holy grail' layout where the footer gets always pushed to the bottom of the page.

css excerpt (see the [jsfiddle for a complete example](https://jsfiddle.net/mqosksza/1/))

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    height: 100%
}
#sky {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    background-color: #0080ff;
}
#plot {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    background-color: #808040;
}
```

In this example the body is the main container and I don't use images for the roof or the house - just css background color and a border triangle. But it demonstrates the concept.

Comment: Could work, but with the bad support of IE this doesn't fit the requirements. :/